# Questions on Sierpinski's theorem, why $f_1(I\cap m(r))\subset f(I)$?

Tags: functions

I'm reading the following [post](http://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/sierpinskis-theorem/) and I have a questions that I cannot resolve:

In the last, or before last paragraph, of the above post the writer makes an observation:

$$r\in f_1(I\cap m(r))\subset f(I)$$

and

$$r\in f_2(I\cap n(r))\subset f(I)$$

I understood that $r\in f_1(I\cap m(r))$, but not the  $f_1(I\cap m(r))\subset f(I)$. **How** one would justify it?

**Also**, afterward he writes "yielding $f_1(I)=f_2(I)=\mathbb{R}$", why is that?

And the **final question**, how he concludes that they both, $f_1,f_2$ have the Darboux property(that property definition is cited at the beginning of his post)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are just a couple of typos that account for all your difficulties.  The $f(I)$ at the end of the first formula you cite should be $f_1(I)$; in the second formula it should be $f_2(I)$.  That correction makes both of the inclusions you asked about trivial.  These two formulas apply to *any* real number $r$, so they show that all real numbers are in both $f_1(I)$ and $f_2(I)$, which answers your second question.  Finally, since $I$ was an arbitrary interval, this means that, for every interval $I$, the images $f_1(I)$ and $f_2(I)$ contain all real numbers $r$ and are therefore intervals, namely the interval $\mathbb R$.  That means $f_1$ and $f_2$ satisfy the definition of the Darboux property.

Comment: Andreas Blass, thank you very much for that, and Happy Holidays!